# JAX-RS client, ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, resteasy, content-length

I have the following method:

```
private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
private static final int TIMEOUT = 5000;
private static final String DATASTREAM_URI = "MY_VALID_URL_HERE";

@Override
public Response logHttpMessage(final String logHttpMessageXml) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    final Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .establishConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .socketTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    final WebTarget target = client.target(DATASTREAM_URI);
    return target.request().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, logHttpMessageXml.getBytes(UTF_8).length)
            .post(Entity.entity(logHttpMessageXml, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));
}
```

I add the header by doing the following: 
**.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, logHttpMessageXml.getBytes(UTF_8).length)**

But I get this error when doing the request:

[image]

NOTE: I need to set the content length in order to disallow chunking, my rest endpoint (out of my control) does NOT react correctly to chunked data.

I´ve been searching the web but did not find a solution, how can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the header is already being set under the hood. Have you done any logging (or used some tool like fiddler) to see the full request with complete headers?

Comment: When I do the following: final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = target.request().post(Entity.entity(logHttpMessageXml, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)).getHeaders(); it says that the value of content-length is 0. Why does this happen?

Comment: These are the response not the request headers. The Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding headers are not set by RESTeasy itself but the underlying Apache HttpClient and I don't think there is an easy way to change this. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332370/content-length-header-already-present?rq=1), [here](http://aruld.info/configuring-chunk-size-in-apache-httpclient-4-3-x/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721554/httpclient-disabling-chunked-encoding)